# Array do not resize after ReDim VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, rows

I was looking here for the answer to my problem but still, do not know how to solve it so I am refreshing the topic.

I have a primitive function that searches in the Worksheet (column A) the inputs to `Userform.TextBox1`, `UserForm.Textbox2`, etc. When a particular record is found, it should assign to an array the record itself and values from next 3 or 4 cells from the same row (each row ends with “End”).  In this way, I will have the array of max 4 columns and as many rows as records will be found
The first `Do` loop goes perfect but increasing the `size` variable  (found records), so increasing the array’s row as I wanted, gives me the `subscript out of range` error. I spent on this a whole day but I do not see what I am missing. 
Here’s the code:

```
Sub test()
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim i, size As Integer
Dim back As String
Cells(1, 1).Select
i = 0
size = 0
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
back = ActiveCell.Address
Do Until ActiveCell = "End"
    size = size + 1
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To size, 1 To 4)
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "End"
        i = i + 1
        arr(size, i) = ActiveCell
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
Loop
Range(back).Offset(1, 0).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
back = ActiveCell.Address
i = 0
Do Until ActiveCell = "End"
    size = size + 1
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To size, 1 To 4)      '"Subscript out of range" error occurs here
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "End"
        i = i + 1
        arr(size, i) = ActiveCell
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If you try to make [mcve] example of your code, most probably you will solve it yourself. Speaking of which, can you create one? :)

Comment: And while doing it, you might want to [avoid using `Select` and other `ActiveCell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Could you post some sample data? Also, could you specify at which line the error occurs?

Comment: @1001001 This should be an/the answer.

Comment: @1001001 Yes, this back-and-forth in the comments doesn't really add anything to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **Preserve** keyword in an array **Redim** declaration it will only redimension the last of array's column. You need to reorganize your arr() array.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the data organizing in the array and it works. Nevertheless, I thought that ReDim in VBA is more flexible (or maybe I do not see this yet but my problem is solved).

Answer (score 0):

To restate your algorithm:

- Search within the first column for the text in `UserForm1.TextBox`. This is the start row of a **block**
- Each block continues until `"End"` appears in the first column
- For each row in the block, you want the values of the cells in that row.
- A cell which contains `"End"` marks the end of the values of the cells in that row.

I would suggest the following general improvements:

- Use a data structure where you don't have to manage the number of elements, as this is very error-prone. Use a `Scripting.Dictionary`, an `ArrayList` or a VBA `Collection`.
- You should not need to manipulate the selected cell. Define a `Range` and iterate over the cells in the `Range`.

Like this:

```
Dim text1 As String
text1 = "Alfa"
Dim text2 As String
text2 = "Kilo"

Dim results As New ArrayList

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

Dim row As Integer
For row = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    Dim firstCellText As String
    firstCellText = rng(row, 1)

    'you might store the possible values in a Dictionary and use Dictionary.Exists for this check
    If firstCellText = text1 Or firstCellText = text2 Then

        Dim cellValues As ArrayList
        Set cellValues = New ArrayList 'this has to be on a separate line

        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In rng.Rows(row).Cells
            If cell = "End" Then Exit For
            cellValues.Add cell.Value
        Next
        results.Add cellValues
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @vonski That's your entire data sample? Five cells in a single row?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You asked for data sample:  
`Alfa NW America 273 End`
and
`Kilo SE Europe 321 End`
I am searching for _Alfa_ and _Kilo_. Then the values of e.g. _NW_, _America_, and _273_  should be stored in one row of the array but the error occurs in the second `ReDim` - 29th row of code when `size` gets the value of 2.

Comment: Basically yes, I try to figure out how to add a row into the array and it was not functioning. That is why I have prepared very basic data just to find the problem.

Comment: @vonski I've updated my answer with some code. As you can see, the code is far simpler when you don't have to manage the size of the array.